# Limit of $\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of $a_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

It seems that the limit is $1$, since $a_n = 0.999...$ for large $n$. The presentation $a_n = \frac{(n^2-1)^n}{n^{2n}}$ and expanding was my first idea, but I couldn't get the result from there. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need this limit for? One place where it crops up is if you define $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ and then want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-1/n)^n=1/e$, in which case some of the answers below will be not so useful.

Comment: Yes, all answers so far use properties of $log$ or $e$. How to figure it out without those properties?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762625/lim-n-to-infty-left1-frac-1n2-rightn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

$$ 1 - \frac{1}{n} \leq \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \leq 1.$$

Comment: On a question asked two days ago, you beat me by 30 seconds :D +1

Comment: I'd say this is "da proof"...+1

Comment: Note also that you can prove the same way that $$\lim\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}\right)^n=1$$ And I think that by looking at the reciprocal you also get  $$\lim\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}\right)^n=1$$

Answer (score 18):

$$\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^{-1}e=1$$

Comment: @AdiDani $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{0}=1$$
because 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{e}$$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}=0$$

Comment: In general, passing to the limit only in *part* of the expression (while leaving the rest still with the variable tending to whatever) is wrong and can easily lead to serious mistakes.

Comment: This is *not* a correct solution.

Comment: Is there a way proving this without using properties of $e$?

Comment: @AdiDani What is this law thou speaketh of?

Comment: It's a simple lemma to prove that if $\;a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}a\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;0<a\;$ , then $\;\sqrt[n]{a_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$. This is based in $\;\sqrt[n]a\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ for $\;a>0\;$. Yet, to *evaluate* part of the expression of a limit while leaving *other* part is wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio Very interesting point, can you give an example that doing this causes mistake?

Comment: Of course, @hhsaffar. Let's take a very well known limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n=1\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks a lot, I learned sth :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for an answer not using the limit leading to $1/e$ how about this?

Using the binomial expansion of $\left( 1-\dfrac1{n^2} \right)^n$ you should be able to set up a series in $n$ and then take the limit.  This series will start out $$1^n + n \cdot 1^{n-1} \cdot \dfrac{-1}{n^2} + \dfrac{n \cdot (n-1)}2 \cdot1^{n-2} \cdot \left( \dfrac{-1}{n^2}\right) ^2 \ldots$$ and from there you should be able to simplify and show that the limit goes to $1$.

Comment: You need some minus signs around there.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I was so focused on the MathJax formatting that I forgot to include the sign.

Comment: Your idea of using the binomial theorem may not be as successful as expected: after all, the *number of summands* dependends on $\;n\;$ and thus we can **not** apply arithmetic of limits there.