# Find supremum and infimum of $(1-1/n^2)^n$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I have to find the supremum and infimum of $(1-1/n^2)^n$ where $n$ is a natural number.
A hint is given that an inequality helps.
I thought that the inequality which could help is Bernoulli's inequality: $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$.
But this is not helping. Because then I get: $(1-1/n^2)^n\ge 1-1/n$ It helps in finding an infimum but not a supremum.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/579415/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since $$\left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n \leq 1$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n =1$$
you get that $$\sup_n \left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n =1$$