# Why is $(1+1/n)^n$ the same as $1/(1-1/n)^n$? I know it's $e$ and $1/(1/e)$ but i want to know why $e$ behaves this way

Tags: calculus

Please help me understand this I know how the limit equals $e$ and $1/e$ but how is this happening I would like to see the proof

Comment: Because of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/579415/42969

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1728752/42969

Comment: A fair amount depends on how you've defined $e$. Sometimes $e$ is *defined* to be that limit; other times, it's defined in some other way (such as the power series) and you have to show that the limit exists and yields the same result as that definition. In your studies, how has $e$ been defined?

Comment: In my studies e hasn't even been introduced lol but thankss

Comment: Algebraic manipulation yields

$$\Big(1-\frac1n\Big)^n=\Big(\frac{n-1}{n}\Big)^n=\frac{1}{\Big(\frac{n}{n-1}\Big)^n}=\frac{1}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\Big)^{n-1}\Big(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\Big)}$$

for $n\geq2$. The term $\Big(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\Big)^{n-1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e$; the term $1+\frac{1}{n-1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$.
Putting things together, one gets $$\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you divide the first expression by the second one, you get
$$
\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{1/(1-1/n)^n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n.
$$
You should be able to show that this converges to $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (can you?). Which proves that the two sequences in the title must have the same limit (assuming either converges).

Answer (score -1):

Observe that $1-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n}$
Thus, we have $$\frac{1}{(1-1/n)^n}=(\frac{n}{n-1})^n=(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^n=(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$$Taking $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}=\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^{n-1} \cdot \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{n}=e \cdot 1=e$